# Create new array based on unique keys

Tags: php, arrays, pivot

I am struggling with an array that I need to convert into a new array based on the unique array keys. My current result looks like below. Each array represent just a part of the desired result (pivot) where I need a [menu_name], [menu_url] and [menu_target] as result and when the next array begins with the same keys, etc. So the way I see it to achieve this is to construct a new array, each time an array_key_exist in the array. But i am unable to achieve this.

```
Array
(
    Array
    (
    [menu_name] => Contact
    )
    Array
    (
    [menu_url] => /contact
    )
    Array
    (
    [menu_target] => _blank
    )
    Array
    (
    [menu_name] => Home
    )
    Array
    (
    [menu_url] => /home
    )
    Array
    (
    [menu_target] => _self
    ) 
)
```

The desired array I want to create looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
    [menu_name] => Contact,
    [menu_url] => /contact,
    [menu_target] => _blank
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
    [menu_name] => Home,
    [menu_url] => /home,
    [menu_target] => _blank
    )
)
```

Here is my code so far (incomplete):

```
$result = array();
foreach($array as $option => $value)
{
    $result[$value->option_key] = $value->option_value;
    $new_array = array();
    if(array_key_exist($value->option_key, $new_array))
    {
        // here is where I get stuck….
    print_r($new_array);
    }
}
```

I hope some one can get me in the right direction to further complete the code with the desired result.

Comment: is this always gonna be grouped by three's?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a var you increment each time key already exists :

```
$result = array();
$i = 0;

foreach($array as $option => $value)
{
    if ( array_key_exists($value->option_key, $result[$i]) ) $i++;

    $result[$i][$value->option_key] = $value->option_value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Djidi, I understand the concept. I am trying your code now.

Comment: Hi Djidi, your answer worked for me! Thanks again. The only change i had to made was $result = array(); to $result[] = array(); Not sure if this needs to be adjusted in your answer? Anyway thanks. I am unable to vote your answer I believe. I dont have enough reputations.

Comment: You're welcome. Normally you don't need to change it.

Comment: @DFA if this did helped you kindly accept this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Provided your answer is always grouped by threes, as posted in your example.

This is an alternative method to [djidi's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24797555/2518525) answer incase you wanted to see it done with silly loops.

```
    $new = array_chunk($a, 3);

    $d = array();
    foreach($new as $i => $group) {
        foreach($group as $index => $item) {
            foreach($item as $name=>$val) {
                $d[$i][$name] = $val;
            }
        }
    }
```

Which returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [menu_name] => Contact
            [menu_url] => /contact
            [menu_target] => _blank
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [menu_name] => Home
            [menu_url] => /home
            [menu_target] => _self
        )
)
```

[**Example Demo**](https://eval.in/173259)

Comment: Hi Darren, Thanks will try you answer.

Comment: @DFA Hey mate, no worries! Any questions, just ask!

Answer (score 0):

Another way, is if the current batch of keys are complete, go to the next one and fill up the next one. Example:

```
$values = array(array('menu_name' => 'Contact'),array('menu_url' => '/contact'),array('menu_target' => '_blank'),array('menu_name' => 'Home'),array('menu_url' => '/home'),array('menu_target' => '_self'),);
$new_values = array();
$x = 0;
$columns = array_unique(array_map(function($var){
    return key($var);
}, $values));

foreach($values as $value) {
    $current_key = key($value);
    $new_values[$x][$current_key] = reset($value);
    if(array_keys($new_values[$x]) == $columns) $x++;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_values);
```

[**Sample Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/f7wEBy)

Comment: Thanks kevinabelita. Currently going for djidi's answer as it's easier for me to understand. But thanks for the contribution!